# How to build a radio app without being affected by doze android?

Tags: android, internet-radio, android-doze-and-standby, doze

Refered to this library https://github.com/iammert/RadioPlayerService
I have this code for playing/pause radio

```
   if (!mRadioManager.isPlaying())
                mRadioManager.startRadio(RADIO_URL[0]);
            else
                mRadioManager.stopRadio();
```

and method for doing processes

```
 @Override
public void onRadioStarted() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Do UI works here.
            mTextViewControl.setText("RADIO STATE : PLAYING...");
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onRadioStopped() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //TODO Do UI works here
            mTextViewControl.setText("RADIO STATE : STOPPED.");
        }
    });
}
```

MyBroadcast Class

```
public class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent1);
}
```

But in android 7 when i turn the screen off  after 5-8 min radio stops playing music. I have done another example by doing in background and it is still the same thing. Please can anyone suggest me how to build a radio app without being affected by doze

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html

Comment: @user1767754  Holding a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK is insufficient to block Doze mode

Comment: If you app goes out of memory, it will be killed, even though you have a wakelock. Maybe that's happening?

Comment: In my example I have to do  long process, in android 6 and below it works perfect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create [Foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) Service for that. Usually when any long process is running (like downloading, playing music or vieo etc.) it creates notification in status bar and lock screen.

> **Note**: You should only use a foreground service for tasks the user expects the system to execute immediately or without interruption. Such cases include uploading a photo to social media, or playing music even while the music-player app is not in the foreground. You should not start a foreground service simply to prevent the system from determining that your app is idle.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your suggestion, I will try to make an example for that, please if you can suggest me an example it will be great, Thanks man

Comment: How to start foreground service you can find by link. For the music panel control I found this: http://sapandiwakar.in/android-media-player-lock-screen/

Comment: Thank You, I really appreciate this, you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

The link below is an extensive example.  Keep in mind that this requires another permission level.
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your suggestion, but if I click the button wich turn the screen off what happens?

Comment: according to documentation  in Doze mode *The system ignores wake locks.* https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html